# Multilanguage support in react router

Tags: react-router

I'm building multilingual site where the language preference is part of the URL, e.g.

```
http://example.com/<somepage>      (Russian, default)
http://example.com/en/<somepage>   (English)
http://example.com/jp/<somepage>   (Japanese)
http://example.com/../             (etc)
```

Everything is ok, when I use prefix for all languages:

```jsx
<Route path="/:lang">
  <Route path="somepage" component={Somepage}/>
</Route>
```

But for default language, I don't need to include language in url, as shown in example. 
In fluxible router it can be solved by using regexp in path:

```
path: '/:lang([a-z]{2})?/<somepage>'
```

But it doesn't work in react router, because path must be a string, not a regexp.
Any ideas how to handle this use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried duplicating your routes? Seems to work for me thus far.

```
var innerRoutes = (
  <Route>
    <Route path="somepage" component={Somepage}/>
    <Route path="otherpage" component={Otherpage}/>
  </Route>
);

var routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    {innerRoutes}
    <Route path=":lang">
      {innerRoutes}
    </Route>
  </Route>
);
```

Comment: What about the innerRoutes are translated too? I've to list all the routes one by one? And if so, when the user change the locale from my application, how can I retrieve the right translated path?

Answer (score 2):

your routes would need to look like:

```jsx
<Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
  <Route component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route path=':lang/'>
      <Route path='about' component={About} />
    </Route>
    <Redirect from='*' to='ru/about' />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

The trailing slash in the `:lang/` indicates that it will only be matched if the URL contains something after it (e.g. `/de/about`) otherwise there is a `Redirect` with a greedy matching which will always redirect to the page you specify in the `to` parameter. You can read more about [Route Matching in the docs](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/RouteMatching.md).

Comment: I don't need a Redirect, I want urls to be exactly like in example for seo purposes.

Comment: I didn't change the look of your URLs they look exactly how you want them to look. I just show you the way you can achieve it with the React Router. Read the route matching docs to see how we match routes.

Comment: I read the docs many times, but I can't understand how to achieve such behavior without regexp. The code below is working like I want, but it's look ugly, I don't like such duplication in routes:
<!-- language: lang-jsx -->

    <Route path="/" component={Application}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
        <Route path="contacts" component={Contacts}/>
        <Route path="partners" component={Partners}/>

        <Route path=":lang" component={Home}/>
        <Route path=":lang/contacts" component={Contacts}/>
        <Route path=":lang/partners" component={Partners}/>
    </Route>

Comment: I just showed you how, React Router provides matching for you. You don't use any regex in your path

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-router v4 and react-intl you can use [react-i18n-routing](https://github.com/FriendsOfECMAScript/ReactI18nRouting) library