# How to set and handle language in react-router from?

Tags: url, reactjs, internationalization, react-router

I have been trying to resolve this all day and finally i come to you all.

The task is simple, I need to set language type in the URL, so it looks something like this: domain.com/{langVar}/other/paths

And be able to change it by clicking/selecting language in my apps header or any other component.

Important: the language variable should always remain in the URL.

I am using "react-router": "^2.7.0", "react": "^15.3.1".

This is how my router config looks like:

```
export default (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/:lang" component={MainApp}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route component={OtherPage} />
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
  </Router>
);
```

I hope this makes, sense if not i will update my question. But to me this seems a pretty normal use case of sites URL.

Thank you

Comment: So what is wrong with what you have?

Comment: I want the lang param to have a default value

Comment: Meaning that if you type in `domain.com/other/path` you'd still have a default language?

Comment: Hey, so when i would type domain.com/other/path it would be a 404, so that does not work, the param should always be in the URL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extending this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33754569/multilanguage-support-in-react-router) question, I added a function called `userRedirect` which will be triggered when the matching route isn't found. Note - the `/` following argument `:lang` in `<Route path=":lang/" >` is very important due to which our route `*` gets hit (as explained in the stack overflow link shared above.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import { App, About } from './containers';

function userRedirect(nextState, replace) {
  var defaultLanguage = 'en-gb';
  var redirectPath = defaultLanguage + nextState.location.pathname
  replace({
    pathname: redirectPath,
  })
};

<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path=":lang/" >
    <Route path="about">
      <Route path="show" component={About}/>
    </Route>
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" onEnter={userRedirect} />
</Route>
```

If you navigate to the url `<domain>/about/show`, it will be redirected to `<domain>/en-gb/about/show`. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: @Arjun what can you say about performance? I would like to use the above pattern to make sure there is always a language parameter in the url. For example, in the app I would use links like this one `<Link to="/posts/latest">posts</Link>` and of course the url would be rewrited to `/default-lang/posts/latest`. Do you think this would be a waste of resources?

Comment: @Jaru Could you please elaborate? I want to achieve the same functionality and tried the example above, but the * Route is not getting triggered, at least not when going to domain.com.

Answer (score 0):

***this answer is almost nice***

```
 function userRedirect(nextState, replace) {
  var defaultLanguage = 'en-gb';
  var redirectPath = defaultLanguage + nextState.location.pathname
  replace({
    pathname: redirectPath,
  })
};

<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path=":lang/" >
    <Route path="about">
      <Route path="show" component={About}/>
    </Route>
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" onEnter={userRedirect} />
</Route>
```

but for me it wasnt good. Since first of all it should be

```
    var redirectPath = defaultLanguage + '/' + nextState.location.pathname
```

links i think should be added not just like "/link-to-page" but "en/link-to-page" because function "userRedirect" is always fired. Every time you click the link. And because of this your url is to become "...en/en/en/en/link-to-page"

Comment: Also i want to hear maybe someone can point me how to handle 404 pages when i will use <Route path="*" onEnter={userRedirect} />