# Convert react-router to v4: Redirect all routes to include lang

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

We've localized our app and now I need to include the lang in all routes, I've come across code that would do what I want but have trouble  doing the same in react-router v4

Here is the code I'm referencing
[How to set and handle language in react-router from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39706654/how-to-set-and-handle-language-in-react-router-from)

Here is the sample code I'm working with to get it functional before integrating it in our app:

```
// add lang to url if it's not present
function langRedirect(props) {
  console.log({ props });
  const defaultLang = 'en';
  const redirectPath = `/${defaultLang}${props.history.location.pathname}`;
  console.log(redirectPath);
  props.history.replace({ pathname: redirectPath, });
}
```

....

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/:lang/" render={() => <h1>testing... does nothing</h1>}>
    <Route path="/:lang/test" render={() => <h2>Test</h2>} />
    <Route path="/:lang/test2" render={() => <h2>Test2</h2>} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" render={langRedirect} />
</Switch>
```

What happens here is if I go to a route like `/test` the switch will still catch the `/:lang/` route even if there is no / at the end which prevents going to the route with `langRedirect`. Seems like a different behaviour in v4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after spending hours on this I happened to figure it out right after posting the question...

I had to add a * to the route like so `<Route exact path="/:lang/*" render={() => <h1>Test</h1>}>`

Here is the working code:

```
// add lang to url if it's not present
function langRedirect(props) {
  console.log({ props });
  const defaultLang = 'en';
  const redirectPath = `/${defaultLang}${props.history.location.pathname}`;
  console.log(redirectPath);
  props.history.replace({
    pathname: redirectPath,
  });
}
```

...

```
const TestingRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/:lang/*" render={() => <h1>Test</h1>}>
        <Route path="/:lang/test" render={() => <h2>Test</h2>} />
        <Route path="/:lang/test2" render={() => <h2>Test2</h2>} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" render={langRedirect} />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```